# How can I use global variable in python class?

Tags: java, python

the Java code runs, while python code not, why?
How can I access global variable inside class in Python?

**Python code:**

```
Definition for a binary tree node.
   class TreeNode(object):
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.val = x
            self.left = None
            self.right = None

previous = None
class Solution(object):
    def isValidBST(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if not root:
            return True
        if not self.isValidBST(root.left):
            return False
        if previous!=None and previous >= root.val:
            return False
        previous = root.val
        return self.isValidBST(root.right)
```

> Line 20: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'previous' referenced before assignment.

**Java code:**

```
 public class Solution {
        private Integer previous = null;
        public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode root) {
            if(root == null){
                return true;
            }
            if(!isValidBST(root.left)){
                return false;
            }
            if(previous != null && previous>=root.val){
                return false;
            }
            previous = root.val;
            return isValidBST(root.right);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
    class Solution(object):
        previous = None
        def isValidBST(self, root):
            """
            :type root: TreeNode
            :rtype: bool
            """
            if not root:
                return True
            if not self.isValidBST(root.left):
                return False
            if self.previous!=None and self.previous >= root.val:
                return False
            self.previous = root.val
            return self.isValidBST(root.right)
```

Note the `previous` is now inside the class, and uses `self.previous` to access it

Edit: To pass it to outside you would need to pass the Solution Object

```
solution = Solution()
#perform something to assign a previous node

test = Test()

test.getPrev(solution)

class Test(object):
    def getPrev(self, solution):
        print solution.previous
```

Comment: How to access it on `outside` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use global keyword.
As previous = None is defined outside class Solution, so to use same variable inside class, add a line.

```
global previous
if previous!=None and previous >= root.val:
    your logic
```

this will do your work.